# How to drag set of elements using snap svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

How to drag set of elements using snap svg?

```
    var s = Snap("#svgmain");
    var onloadmap = Snap.load("SVGFILES/3k1e-test.svg",function(lf)
    {
    s.append(lf);
    var all_rect = s.selectAll('rect');
    var all_path = s.selectAll('path');
    group_of_rects_and_paths.push(all_path,all_rect);
    var dragger = function() {
            this.ox = this.type == "rect" ? this.attr("x") : this.attr("cx");
            this.oy = this.type == "rect" ? this.attr("y") : this.attr("cy");
        },
        move = function(dx, dy) {
            var mx = Number(this.ox) + dx;
            var my = Number(this.oy) + dy;
            var att = this.type == "rect" ? {
                x: mx,
                y: my
            } : {
                cx: mx,
                cy: my
            };
            this.attr(att);
        },
        up = function() {
        };
    group_of_rects_and_paths.drag(move,dragger,up);
    })
```

But nothing heppend with set of elements, only error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What is wrong?
Please help.

Problem solved:

```
    var g = s.group();
    var onloadmap = Snap.load("SVGFILES/3k1e-test.svg",function(lf)
    {
    g.append(lf);
    ......
    g.drag();
```

But here is a new proble.
How to drag this group in border?

Comment: Can you pop it on a fiddle ? (normal way would probably to use a group and drag that with a transform)

Comment: Looking at it, I'm not sure sets support drag, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but here is a new proble. How to drag this group in border?

Comment: Not sure what you mean ?